# How to fit a smooth line to some points but preserve monotonicity

Tags: r, smoothing, kernel-density

I have the following data points

```
example<-structure(list(y = c(1, 0.961538461538462, 0.923076923076923, 
0.884615384615385, 0.846153846153846, 0.807692307692308, 0.769230769230769, 0.730769230769231, 0.730769230769231, 0.730769230769231, 0.687782805429864, 0.687782805429864, 0.641930618401207, 0.596078431372549, 0.596078431372549, 0.54640522875817, 0.496732026143791, 0.496732026143791, 0.496732026143791, 
0.496732026143791, 0.496732026143791, 0.496732026143791, 0.496732026143791, 0.496732026143791, 0.496732026143791, 0.496732026143791, 0.496732026143791
), x = c(0, 59, 115, 156, 268, 329, 353, 365, 377, 421, 431, 
448, 464, 475, 477, 563, 638, 744, 769, 770, 803, 855, 1040, 
1106, 1129, 1206, 1227)), .Names = c("y", "x"), row.names = c(NA, 
-27L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to fit a smooth line. There are several methods in R to do it, using `loess`, `ksmooth`, `locpoly` etc.

Is there any way however to **ensure** or **force** that the resulting smoothed line will be **monotonic** (in the case of the present example monotonically decreasing?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `scam()` function in the *scam* package for uni- or multivariate smoothing with constraints. The help file,  `?scam:::shape.constrained.smooth.terms` shows all of the available options. For example, the B-spline basis which is used for smoothing can be penalized to yield monotonically decreasing coefficients with `scam(y~s(x,bs="mpd"))`.

```
require(scam)   

attach(example)

yhat <- predict(scam(y~s(x,bs="mpd")),se=TRUE)

plot(x,y)
lines(x,y=yhat$fit)
lines(x,y=yhat$fit+1.96*yhat$se.fit,lty=2)
lines(x,y=yhat$fit-1.96*yhat$se.fit,lty=2)
```